# Grub boots windows 8, but not ubuntu 13.04

Tags: installation, dual-boot, grub2, windows-8, uefi

So when I start my computer grub comes up just fine and I have 4 options. Ubuntu; Advanced options for Ubuntu; Windows UEFI bkgbootmgfw.ofi; windows boot UEFI loader. The Windows boot UEFI loader option starts windows 8 just fine. When I choose the Ubuntu option I get nothing but a blank purple screen.

The advanced Ubuntu options have a bit of text displayed when I select them, but they still do nothing. They are Ubuntu, with Linux 3.8.0-19-generic; Ubuntu, with Linux 3.8.0-19-generic (recovery mode). The text before the system hangs is

```
Starting Linux 3.8.0-19-generic ...
Loading initial Ram Disk ...
```

I have been trying to install Ubuntu 13.04 to duel boot with Windows 8 using UEFI. I followed the instructions here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI . Of note is that I was unable to directly install Ubuntu in UEFI mode. I had to install it in Legacy and then use boot-repair to convert it to UEFI as instructed in the link above. When I clicked apply it asked me to execute a few commands in the terminal.

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -fy
sudo apt-get purge -y --force-yes grub*-common suim-signed Linux-signed*
```

It asked me if I wanted to remove grub. I said yes. Then it had me enter

```
sudo apt-get install-y --force-yes grub-efi Linux
```

So I reinstalled Ubuntu redid all of the steps above but recorded the link boot-repair gave me. [Here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5970516/)

I don't believe that this is related but I also put my swap partition on a second hard drive.

Any Idea how to fix this or where I went wrong while converting Ubuntu to UEFI?

My Computer: Cyberpower PC Fangbook X7-200

- CPU: Intel(R) Core™ i7-3630QM Mobile Processor 2.40 GHz
- Motherboard: Intel HM77 Express Chipset Mainboard
- HDD: 128GB OCZ Octane SATA-III
- HDD2: 750GB 7200RPM SATA300
- Memory: 16GB (4GBx4) DDR3-1600 SODIMM
- Video: NVIDIA GTX 675MX
- Video: Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000

Comment: Did you write down or copy the link for bootinfoscript? Post in q if you did. Load boot-repair again if you didn't and generate bootinfoscript without doing anymore changes and then post link in q. How about adding some hardware specs? make and model would be good.

Comment: You said that using the advanced boot options produce text before the system hangs. Please report what this text is. (If it's a lot, try taking a photo with a digital camera and post a link to the image. Make sure it's legible.)

Answer (score 1):

GRUB correctly appears and lets you boot Windows, so you have successfully converted Ubuntu in UEFI mode.
Now, your issue is probably due to wrong graphic drivers. Eg look at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee for your Nvidia card.